# Relative position with TransformToAncestor

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvas (ZoomableCanvas) which implements zooming and has child items. I'm trying to get the relative position of a child item when zooming in, in order to display extended information over it.

```
<Canvas x:Name="CanvasContainer" Width="1500" Height="780">
    <ZoomableCanvas ApplyTransform="false" Loaded="ZoomableCanvas_Loaded" x:Name="ShareCanvas" Width="1500" Height="780" MinWidth="1500" MinHeight="780" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
</Canvas>
```

Code behind:

```
Canvas main = touched.FindVisualParent<Canvas>(); //Finds "CanvasContainer"
Point relativePoint = touched.TransformToAncestor(main).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
double canvasTop = Canvas.GetTop(touched);
```

But here canvasTop != relativePoint.Y before zooming?

Am I using this incorrectly. Doesn't it map to the parent visual and give a relative point?

Comment: Why the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` on the ZoomableCanvas?

Comment: Leftover from a change. Thanks for pointing that bit of sloppiness out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you're comparing will only be equal if

- There is no transform (RenderTranform or LayoutTransform) set on
  `touched`, since these are taken into account in `TransformToAncestor` but
  not in the `Canvas.Left` or `Canvas.Top` properties.
- The ZoomableCanvas has no offset relative to the outer canvas. This
  is because `Canvas.GetTop(touched)` returns the top offset relative
  to the ZoomableCanvas (assumed that `touched` is a child of the
  ZoomableCanvas), whereas `relativePoint` is relative to the outer
  Canvas.

---

To illustrate the first issue, just put an element with a RenderTransform into a Canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Label x:Name="child" Content="Hello" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="50" Y="100"/>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
    </Label>
</Canvas>
```

If you'd call

```
var point = child.TransformToAncestor(canvas).Transform(new Point());
var left = Canvas.GetLeft(child);
var top = Canvas.GetTop(child);
```

it would return `point` as (100, 200), whereas `left` is 50 and `top` is 100.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I understand due to your explanation. I'm not doing a transform on the child items. I am adding them in code behind though. I suspect this may be the issue as I get 0,0 for a relativePoint.

Comment: And (0,0) would be perfectly ok unless you haven't set Canvas.Left or Canvas.Top.

Comment: Think I found it, I was clearing all of the children and re-adding them to reset. If I don't do this it works correctly as per your excellent explanation.